# Apply two-proportions z-test to each row in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a two-proportions z-test to each row of a dataset in R (see below) using the prop.test function. Ideally I would like to create a new variable/column which held the p-value

```
print(df)

   Financial_Year YOT                  Ethnicity_Group   x1    n1    x2   n2
   <chr>          <chr>                <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Asian              11   202  2933 20537
 2 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Black              48   202  4846 20537
 3 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Mixed              16   202  1460 20537
 4 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Other              11   202   296 20537
 5 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham White             116   202 11002 20537
```

i have used the following code, but it [provides a value for all the dataframe and I want to provide a value for each row

```
prop.test(x=c(df$x1,df$x2),n=c(df$n1,df$n2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows of the subset of columns

```
out <- apply(df[c("x1", "x2", "n1", "n2")], MARGIN = 1, 
       FUN = function(x) prop.test(x[1:2], n = x[3:4]))
```

-output

```
> out[[1]]

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  x[1:2] out of x[3:4]
X-squared = 12.107, df = 1, p-value = 0.0005024
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.12251538 -0.05420454
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.05445545 0.14281541
```

---

Or using `rowwise` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(prop_out = list(prop.test(c(x1, x2), n = c(n1, n2)))) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  Financial_Year YOT                  Ethnicity_Group    x1    n1    x2    n2 prop_out
  <chr>          <chr>                <chr>           <int> <int> <int> <int> <list>  
1 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Asian              11   202  2933 20537 <htest> 
2 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Black              48   202  4846 20537 <htest> 
3 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Mixed              16   202  1460 20537 <htest> 
4 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham Other              11   202   296 20537 <htest> 
5 2013-14        Barking and Dagenham White             116   202 11002 20537 <htest>
```

---

As it is rowwise, it may be efficient to do this with `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(slt(df, c(x1, x2, n1, n2)), MARGIN = 1, 
    FUN = function(x) broom::tidy(prop.test(x[1:2], x[3:4])))
```

-output

```
 estimate1          estimate2            statistic              p.value parameter            conf.low          conf.high
1 0.0544554455445545  0.142815406339777     12.1067023956426  0.00050240906422549         1  -0.122515378571079 -0.054204543019366
2  0.237623762376238   0.23596435701417 4.76180917991616e-29    0.999999999999994         1  -0.058981691254255 0.0623005019783911
3 0.0792079207920792 0.0710912012465306   0.0954759943764134    0.757327688266023         1 -0.0317907296528701 0.0480241687439672
4 0.0544554455445545 0.0144130106636802     19.3321963867166 1.09838571600508e-05         1 0.00620835983330951  0.073876509928439
5  0.574257425742574  0.535716024735843      1.0448222622193    0.306702587391334         1 -0.0324851306596845  0.109567932673148
                                                                method alternative
1 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction   two.sided
2 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction   two.sided
3 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction   two.sided
4 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction   two.sided
5 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction   two.sided
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Financial_Year = c("2013-14", "2013-14", "2013-14", 
"2013-14", "2013-14"), YOT = c("Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham"
), Ethnicity_Group = c("Asian", "Black", "Mixed", "Other", "White"
), x1 = c(11L, 48L, 16L, 11L, 116L), n1 = c(202L, 202L, 202L, 
202L, 202L), x2 = c(2933L, 4846L, 1460L, 296L, 11002L), n2 = c(20537L, 
20537L, 20537L, 20537L, 20537L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```